# Sampling from data

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, signal-processing, sample

I want to get some number of sample from some files.

However, in some file there is no enough sample to take.

In this case, I just want to skip this file and pass to next file. Can anyone know, how can I do this. I added my code below.

```
for m=1:size(examples,1)
      ValuesInChannel=data(:,channel+4); 
      ESUTime= data(:,18);
      ValuesWithinLimit=ValuesInChannel(find(ESUTime>=examples(m) & ESUTime<=limit1(m)));
      SampleFromEdf=datasample(ValuesWithinLimit,20,'Replace',false);
      SampleFromEdfwithchannel(m,:)=[SampleFromEdf',channel];
 end
```

In this part of my script, my sample size is `20`.

As I said above, in some file, it is not possible to get `20` samples, in this case, I just want to pass next file to get samples. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you want to skip the loop when `length(ValuesWithinLimit)<20`,

```
n = 0;
for m=1:size(examples,1)
      ValuesInChannel=data(:,channel+4); 
      ESUTime= data(:,18);
      ValuesWithinLimit=ValuesInChannel(find(ESUTime>=examples(m) & ESUTime<=limit1(m)));
      if length(ValuesWithinLimit)<20
         continue;
      else
         n = n + 1;
      end
      SampleFromEdf=datasample(ValuesWithinLimit,20,'Replace',false);
      SampleFromEdfwithchannel(n,:)=[SampleFromEdf',channel];
 end
```

Comment: @Ram if you use `break` then you will get out of the loop and you won't try other data. But `continue` will just escape one `m`.